Since I updated chrome to version 129, the default download directory has stopped working
Since chrome updated to version 129, I'm having trouble setting the default download folder for the Chrome driver.
How should I configure this default folder now?
public WebDriver newDriver() {
        
    WebDriverManager.getInstance(DriverManagerType.CHROME).setup();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    options.addArguments("--log-net-log");
        
    Map<String, String> prefs = new HashMap<>();
    prefs.put("download.default_directory",
    System.getProperty(("C:\\Users\\JTomassi\\Desktop\\SSEG_Portales\\Documentos")));
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);


prefs.put("download.default_directory",     System.getProperty(("C:\\Users\\JTomassi\\Desktop\\SSEG_Portales\\Documentos"))); --  This looks not correct. It should be just the path without System.getProperty

should also be, HashMap<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();  though not sure <string, string> or Map interface/type would cause any issue here...
